# How to get data from mysql database based on array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I have table called paint with data like below

```
id            name               allow_on
------------------------------------------
1             Avian           Wall|Roof|Wood
2             Avitex          Wall|Roof|Iron
3             Nippon          Floor|Iron
4             Some            Plastic|Cloth|other
```

And how to get field based on `allow_on` column, like "I want paint which can be used on wall" , so far my code look like this

```
$paints = Paint::get();
foreach($paints as $paint)
{
     $exp = explode("|", $paint->allow_on);
     foreach($exp as $pnt)
     {
         if(in_array($request->paint_name,$pnt))
         {
            var_dump($pnt)
         }
     }
}
```

I'm using Laravel 5.4 but i can't make it working, any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: actually, I didn't know how to query data based on request what I explained above, (I want paint whic can be used on wall), so I need suggestion how to query that data :D

Comment: Your problem stems from bad database design. Putting data in a column as a delimited list. It makes querying that data far more complex.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you suggest the good database design??

Comment: GOOGLE `mysql database design tutorial`

Comment: ok the most best solution >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$want    = 'Wall';
$allowed = Paint::where('allow_on', 'like', '%'.$want.'%')->get();

foreach ($allowed as $allowedPaint) {
    echo $allowedPaint->name;
}
```

The above will get you all paints which can be used on wall. If you need to retrieve only the paint names, you can use:

```
$allowed = Paint::where('allow_on', 'like', '%'.$want.'%')->pluck('name');
var_dump($allowed);
```

Comment: But i got an empty object :/

Comment: @RizalFakhri `$allowed` in the first case will be an eloquent collection and in the second case will be an array. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry my mistake >_< Case Sensitive, Thx it's works :D

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the use of the needle and haystack when using  [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

The haystack should be an array i.e. the `$exp` array in your example

```
$paints = Paint::get();
foreach($paints as $paint)
{
     $exp = explode("|", $paint->allow_on);

    if(in_array($request->paint_name,$exp)) {
            // yes paint_name is in the array
     }
}
```